# HTML5 : Synchronous communication between Web-worker thread and main thread

Tags: web-worker

Is there any way to achieve synchronous communication between the main thread and the web worker threads? I know the communication is only through postMessage which is async, but any other way (say using sync IndexedDB APIs) that this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

[SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) will give you synchronous access to shared memory. Which can be used as a mechanism for synchronous communication.

However, it does require a secure context.

Answer (score -1):

Dont think it is possible , but if it helps, you could consider using deferreds for a cleaner Async flow.

so if you have synchronous flow like:

```
var n = 71, 
x = checkPrime(71);
alert(x); //display if n is prime or not.
```

// can be converted to async:

```
var dfd = useWorkerForPrime(71);
dfd.done(function(isPrime) {   alert (x); //display if prime  })
```

you return a deferred from 'useWorkerForPrime' that resolves once the message is received from the worker.

Reference for more about deferreds: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery